# grails -Dgrails.env=xxx always says "Script Xxx" not found,did you mean

Tags: grails

Grails 2.5, Java 7 64bit, windows 8.1

This is very odd. We have a large app, and I am the only windows user (everyone else on macs). For some reason, I cannot do anything with environments on the command line.

E.g. I can do this:

```
grails run-app
```

But I cannot do this:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=myenv run-app
```

It always says:

Script 'Myenv' not found, did you mean...

In my DataSource.groovy, I have:

```
 environments {
     development {
        dataSource {
        // stuff
     }
     myenv {
       // same stuff as the above stuff
     }
 }
```

It works for other users, just not me.

Any ideas how I debug this? It means I have not been able to do development, as I need multiple envs to do liquibase diffs etc.

Comment: The params come after the script name. e.g.: `grails run-app -Dgrails.env=myenv`

Comment: wasn't there some problem on windows, where you had to pass the params like this in quotes?  like `grails "-Dgrails.env=myenv" ...` ?

Comment: Brilliant that's it!  submit it as an answer and ill tick...

Comment: I had a similar issue that resolved after running "grails refresh-dependencies"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you have to pass the params in quotes, like this:

```
grails "-Dgrails.env=myenv" ...
```

The docs mention only the way it can be used with the shell script.  Either windows or the used `grails.bat` behave differently.

Comment: Sadly i have no reference/source for this

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are passing the parameters to the `run-app` script before the script name. You should use:

`grails run-app -Dgrails.env=myenv`

Comment: Not according to the documentation, e.g. https://grails.org/wiki/Environments It says : grails [environment] [command name]